# Git: Make auto-merge files into conflicted ones

Tags: java, git, github

I have a github repository that has some code. Another person forked that repository and cloned it. They changed some code. I want to replace all of my code with their code (accept all their changes). I've run

```
git pull -X theirs https://github.com/epicmanmoo/JavaStudyBuddies.git master
```

which works fine for conflicted files, it removes my code, leaving theirs.
The issue is it is only so for files with ===== >>>>> <<<< stuff in them (conflicted files).

The problem are files like `Column.java` which are not marked as conflicted.

**Column.java**:

```java
package javastudybuddies.discordbots.entities;

public enum Column {
    NAME("name", "name", "projects"),
    DESCRIPTION("description", "description",  "projects"),
    STATUS("status", "status", "projects"),
    COMPLETED("completed", "completed", "projects"),
    DIFFICULTY("difficulty", "difficulty", "projects"),
    TYPE("type", "type", "projects"),

    USERNAME("username", "username", "users"), LEVEL("level", "level", "users"),
    COUNTRY("country", "country", "users"), TIMEZONE("timezone", "timezone", "users"),
    AGE("age", "age", "users"), IDSTRING("id_string", "id", "users"), TAGSTRING("tag_string", "tag", "users"),
    GOAL("goal", "goal", "users"), TECH("tech", "tech", "users");

    public final String databaseLabel;
    public final String userLabel;
    public final String table;
...
```

And in 
https://github.com/epicmanmoo/JavaStudyBuddies/blob/master/src/main/java/javastudybuddies/discordbots/entities/Column.java

it's

```java
public enum Column {
    NAME("name", "name", "projects"),
    DESCRIPTION("description", "description",  "projects"),
    STATUS("status", "status", "projects"),
    TYPE("type", "type", "projects"),
    COMPLETED("completed", "completed", "projects"),
    DIFFICULTY("difficulty", "difficulty", "projects"),

    USERNAME("username", "username", "users"), LEVEL("level", "level", "users"),
    COUNTRY("country", "country", "users"), TIMEZONE("timezone", "timezone", "users"),
    AGE("age", "age", "users"), IDSTRING("id_string", "id", "users"), TAGSTRING("tag_string", "tag", "users"),
    GOAL("goal", "goal", "users"), TECH("tech", "tech", "users");

    public final String databaseLabel;
    public final String userLabel;
    public final String table;
    ...
```

See the difference? In my version TYPE is the last, in his version TYPE is in the middle, so that doesn't even register as a merge conflict.

For debugging I've run the usual version of `git pull` (without `-X theirs`):

`git pull https://github.com/epicmanmoo/JavaStudyBuddies.git master`

That version, too, does this:

```java
public enum Column {
    NAME("name", "name", "projects"),
    DESCRIPTION("description", "description",  "projects"),
    STATUS("status", "status", "projects"),
    TYPE("type", "type", "projects"),
    COMPLETED("completed", "completed", "projects"),
    DIFFICULTY("difficulty", "difficulty", "projects"),
    TYPE("type", "type", "projects"),

    USERNAME("username", "username", "users"), LEVEL("level", "level", "users"),
    COUNTRY("country", "country", "users"), TIMEZONE("timezone", "timezone", "users"),
    AGE("age", "age", "users"), IDSTRING("id_string", "id", "users"), TAGSTRING("tag_string", "tag", "users"),
    GOAL("goal", "goal", "users"), TECH("tech", "tech", "users");

    public final String databaseLabel;
    public final String userLabel;
    public final String table;
```

and doesn't include the file in

`git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U`
(list of conflicted files)

while another file, say, ProjectsBot.java is marked as conflicted
and when I open it, I see this

```java
<<<<<<< HEAD
public class ProjectsBot extends ListenerAdapter  {
    private enum Command  {
=======
public class ProjectsBot extends ListenerAdapter {
    private enum Command {
>>>>>>> b858d8ab9c06ee2645a0dda716d9b5e14a6db11d
        CREATE_PROJECT("create project \"name\", \"description\", \"difficulty\""),
        JOIN_PROJECT("join project 'name\"");

        public final String syntax;

<<<<<<< HEAD
        Command(String syntax)  {
=======
        Command(String syntax) {
>>>>>>> b858d8ab9c06ee2645a0dda716d9b5e14a6db11d
            this.syntax = syntax;
        }
    }
```

So, my problem is, if not for files like `Column.java`,

```
git pull -X theirs https://github.com/epicmanmoo/JavaStudyBuddies.git master
```

would have been the ideal solution - it automatically accepts their changes and I can push them right away. Is there a way to make it work for files like `Column.java`? Make them look somewhat like this inwardly:

```
>>>>HEAD
    NAME("name", "name", "projects"),
    DESCRIPTION("description", "description",  "projects"),
    STATUS("status", "status", "projects"),
    COMPLETED("completed", "completed", "projects"),
    DIFFICULTY("difficulty", "difficulty", "projects"),
    TYPE("type", "type", "projects"),
=====
   NAME("name", "name", "projects"),
    DESCRIPTION("description", "description",  "projects"),
    STATUS("status", "status", "projects"),
    TYPE("type", "type", "projects"),
    COMPLETED("completed", "completed", "projects"),
    DIFFICULTY("difficulty", "difficulty", "projects"),
>>>>theircommit
```

so that the `-X theirs` option could replace everything above `=====` with everything below it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no, you can't do that.

The long answer is that you *can* do that, but you must write your own merge strategy: not just a merge driver, and not a strategy *option* like `-X theirs`, but a *strategy* like `-s my-new-strategy`, which will have Git invoke `git-merge-my-new-strategy`, which means you have to have a command spelled that way in your `$PATH`.  Writing a strategy is very hard (one way to start would be to clone a copy of Git, and then copy the existing recursive strategy to a new one and write a bunch of new C code in your new strategy, using the recursive strategy as the starting point).

If there are not too many files involved, I would recommend instead using:

```
git checkout <branch>
git merge --no-commit <options> <commit-specifier>
```

then resolve each file manually, using whatever technique you find best.  The `--no-commit` means that regardless of whether Git thinks the merge succeeded or not—with `-X theirs` it will usually think the merge succeeded—the merge will stop *as if* there had been conflicts, which lets you edit and `git add` files.

When you're all done—and it's useful to use `git diff HEAD` or `git diff --cached HEAD` now and then to compare what you have in the work-tree (first command) or index (second command) to the `HEAD` commit, to see what will be different in your final merge result—run:

```
git merge --continue
```

to commit the merge, or:

```
git commit
```

if your Git is too old to support `git merge --continue`.  (The `git merge --continue` command just runs `git commit`, but makes there that there *is* a merge to commit before running `git commit`, so it acts as a check to make sure nothing else has gone wrong.  For instance if you accidentally do a `git reset` while you're resolving things, you may have removed the merge state.  In this case, the final `git commit` would just make an ordinary non-merge commit, instead of making a merge commit.  That's recoverable too, but it's more annoying to fix it than it is to not make the mistake in the first place—so `git merge --continue` is a good thing.)